# WebStorm does not compile some files on save

Tags: ubuntu, webstorm

I have problems with compiling files on save. I'm using WebStorm on Ubuntu 16. I tried to reinstall WebStorm but same problem again. Here is my tsconfig file:

```
    {
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Files inside folders with red underline are not compiling on save, with green underline are compiling on save.

[image: Files inside folders with red underline are not compiling on save, with green underline are compiling on save.]

Comment: do you use the Typescript compiler service ( *Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript, Recompile on changes*) or  file watcher, etc. to compile your files?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

in file:

```
/etc/sysctl.conf
```